# extract method into template with global scope, something similar to extract function

Tags: php, templates, extract

I create my mini-micro framework. In my class which loads template I have property named $variable. This property stores array of viariables which should be available in my template.

For example:

```
$this->variable = array($key=>5, $data=>10);
```

Next, I use function extract()

```
extract($this->variable);
```

So, now in my template(test.html.php) I have simple access to passed variables:

test.html.php

```
echo $key;
```

I also have method named import().
In my template I have access for this method by operator $this

test.html.php

```
$this->import();
```

Is there any possibility to call my function import() in template, without operator $this?

Answer (score 0):

Have your template implement the [__invoke()](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.invoke) magic method.

```
class Template {
    ......

    public function __invoke() {
        $this->import();
    }
}
```

Set a variable named `import` which is equal to `$this`.

```
$this->variable['import'] = $this;
```

When you extract the variables a variable named `$import` will be available and if you do `$import()` in the template it should call the `__invoke()` method of the template class which in turn calls the `import()` method of the class.

You should try and refrain from calling methods in templates though if possible. You should just be dealing with variables. A little call to `$import()` somewhere in there may not be the worst thing in the world, it depends what that method is doing.

Comment: "You should try and refrain from calling methods in templates though if possible." That would help to have clean templates, but it's a common practice to call ViewHelpers inside templates to apply content transformation, translation or formatting to variables.

Comment: Those things should be done in a view, not a template. The template then just deals with variables created by the view.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, please try to avoid using extract() and the global scope.

**be careful, when using extract()**

extract() is a very dynamic language feature, which tends to cause clashes with variables already existing in the local scope. You have to take care of that by using the second 
parameter, which controls the newly created variables.

- (EXTR_SKIP) including not overwriting any existing variables ,
- (EXTR_IF_EXISTS) ONLY overwriting existing variables (so you can create a whitelist)
- (EXTR_PREFIX_ALL) or by adding prefixes to the variables

extract() causes developer confusion, because new developers on your project, simply don't grasp were variables are coming from.

[extract() is also a performance killer](http://hhvm.com/blog/713/hhvm-optimization-tips), in regards to using it with HHVM, because of the extra book-keeping of scoped-variables, which needs to be done. In short: avoid it, when optimizing for speed on HHVM.

---

Still it's common practice to use extract in the View object, like so:

**using extract() in a View object**

```
// View.php
class View {

    public $variables;

    function render($filename) {
        extract($this->variables);
        ob_start();
        $this->returned = include($this->dir . $this->filename);
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

// test.php
$view = new View;
$view->variables = array('test' => 'Hello World!');    
$template = __DIR__.'/test.tpl';

echo $view->render($template);

// var_dump($view->returned); // to see included template content

// Template: test.tpl
<p><?php echo $test; ?></p>
```

---

If you really want to pollute the global scope:

**Merge Variable to $GLOBALS**

`$GLOBALS += $vars;`

```
function globalize($data) {  
  $GLOBALS += $data;
}

$vars = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2);
globalize($vars);
echo $a; // prints 1
```

**foreach with creating dynamic global variables from key names**

```
foreach($array as $var_name => $var_value)
{
   global $$var_name;
   $$var_name = $var_value;
}
```

or better (to avoid clashes) directly add to GLOBALS array.

```
foreach($array as $var_name => $var_value)
{
   $GLOBALS[$var_name] = $var_value;
}
```

**Works, but is evil...**